# Firebase chat app in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

In android studio i'm create a messaging app using Fire-base but when i was launch my app its display a main_activity for a seconds then display a login page when i was successfully login app is crash what should i do please help me my code was perfect i think there is something black in my manifest Please help me out to solve this problem ..

Here IS MANIFEST CODE ...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.syedqadri.message">

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
                 </activity>


        </application>

    </manifest>
```

HERE IS MY GRADLE(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my Gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.syedqadri.message"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'



    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
   // compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my java MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.syedqadri.message;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<chatmessage> adapter;
    RelativeLayout activity_main;
    FloatingActionButton sent;


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_signout){
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>(){

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task){

                    Snackbar.make(activity_main, "You Have Been Sign Out", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE){

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Snackbar.make(activity_main, "Signing in SucessFully.Welcome ...",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                displaychatmessage();

            }
            else{
                Snackbar.make(activity_main, "Try Again Later ...",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity_main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        sent =   (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.sent);
        sent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new chatmessage(input.getText().toString(),FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()));
                input.setText("");
                input.requestFocus();
              //  displaychatmessage();
            }
        });

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null){
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        else{

            Snackbar.make(activity_main, "Welcome" +FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            displaychatmessage();
        }
        //load content
        displaychatmessage();
    }

    private void displaychatmessage() {

        ListView listOfMessage = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_message);
        adapter =  new FirebaseListAdapter<chatmessage>(this,chatmessage.class,R.layout.list,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {


            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, chatmessage model, int position) {
                //get reference to the list view items.xml
                TextView messageText,messageUser,messageTime;
                messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                messageText.setText(model.getMessaegeText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",model.getMessageTime()));

            }
        };

        listOfMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here is my Chatmessage.java

```
package com.example.syedqadri.message;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Syed Qadri on 09-Jun-17.
 */
public class chatmessage {

    private String messaegeText;
    private  String messageUser;
    private long messageTime;

    public chatmessage(String messaegeText, String messageUser) {
       this.messaegeText = messaegeText;
       this.messageUser = messageUser;

        messageTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
    public chatmessage() {
    }
    public String getMessaegeText() {
        return messaegeText;
    }

    public void setMessaegeText(String messaegeText) {
        this.messaegeText = messaegeText;
    }

    public String getMessageUser() {
        return messageUser;
    }

    public void setMessageUser(String messageUser) {
        this.messageUser = messageUser;
    }

    public long getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }

    public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read about a [mcve]. And if the code crashed, you forgot about the logcat

Comment: i will also provide the logcat of my code below

Comment: No, don't put it below, you are allowed to edit the initial question. Also, I don't see any crash in there. Try using the filtering functionality of Android Studio to get just your app logs

Comment: Ok let me check

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I think you forgot to add the **Internet permissions** in your manifest file 
Put this line above ur application tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: basically my app show main screen before login in app and after login in app it will crash ..

Comment: @Umer Your initial post was missing this. Read the logcat, and it tells you exactly where and why the code crashes, usually

Comment: my app doesn't connect with firebase

Comment: dude @Umer Yousuf .. I think you should comment out those dependencies that you have commented in your build.gradle. 
and do one thing, also add the firebase-database dependency in your gradle. Also make sure that you have enabled the Firebase Auth - Sign In methods from firebase console in order to implement Authentication